# Dialogflow does not pick up list parameter correctly

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a serious strange problem with dialogflow. Please see the following pictures:

[image: d1]

[image: d2]

[image: d3]

[image: d4]

When I try this sentence "Let's set up a new FMR under fmr test with rents, studio at 1000, one bedroom at 1200, two bedroom rented at 1400, three bedroom priced at 1600 and four bedroom at 1800.", it only picks up some of "number"s.

Would you please help me on this to figure out why this happens? Is there any limitation in the number of "list" parameters members?

Answer (score 0):

You need to break up your singular, multi-line training phrase into several training phrases in order for your intent to pick up expected user utterances and more generally, for your agent to work properly. You can reach the official documentation all about training phrases [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/training-phrases). You will need around 15-20 training phrases at minimum.